# Is data recovery possible in encrypted phone?

Tags: data-recovery, android-10, disk-encryption

I need a suggestion!
Tomorrow I am giving my phone to service centre for repairing my broken camera. I am feared that whether they can access my files or not?
My phone is on android 10 out of the box and it is encrypted by default. I am going to reset my phone before giving it to the service centre. Is it possible to recover data on a encrypted phone?

Comment: if your bootloader is locked a simple lock screen pin/password (min 5 digits) is already enough. no need to factory reset. nevertheless factory reset will wipe encryption key(s) therefore recovery is impossible

Comment: @alecxs But a locked device would make it difficult for the service to test the replaced camera, or do they have signed boot images for hardware testing that can be loaded on-the-fly like `fastboot boot img`?

Comment: @Robert true, in that case factory reset is recommended. Although on some devices you can access camera on lock screen. i doubt service center has special access, except for the manufacturer itself maybe

Comment: @10E_13_ Bipin remove all google accounts before factory reset (to avoid FRP lock)